# custom JDBC driver for SAP Business Objects

Tags: debugging, jdbc, business-objects

I'm writting custom JDBC driver for my datasource. I'd like to use it with Business Objects product from SAP. My driver works fine in Squirell SQL, but when installed in Business Objects (specifically Universe Designer) I'm unable to fetch table contents. I've enabled TRACE for whole Business Objects instance and the problem's log looks like this:

```
dictionary_thread::Columns : CS:Unexpected behavior
com.businessobjects.connectionserver.RDBMSDictionary}.Columns: [com.sap.connectivity.cs.core.CSError: Unexpected behavior
```

As for debugging my JDBC driver, I've been using log4jdbc as well as custom logging of method calls and return values (via aspects) and I don't see any errors, exceptions coming from my driver.

Perhaps someone knows a solution for this, or knows how to debug this further?

It seems obvious that my driver is not fully JDBC specs comformant, so any Test Suite which could analyze errors in my driver would also be of use.

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC API Test Suite 1.3.1 is quite outdated but it may help you diagnose your issue, at least for JDBC 2.0 API: [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-141179.html) is no longer available, remains an old [Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jdbctestsuite-1-3-1-140675.html)

According to [JSR221 for JDBC4](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) you may ask for [JavaSE TCK (JCK)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit) sources at no charge but you have to follow [this process](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/). You will have to accept [OpenJDK TCK license](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/).

Comment: This isn't enough since the site you've linked to does not allow downloading the test suite. The link is dead.